# Check & filter outgoing mails in Postfix

Tags: postfix, email

I am looking for a way to check outgoing mails with rules like :

- mails sent to a particular domain
- mails sent without subject or with a specific subject
- mails with an attachment of a certain size
- mails sent to x recipients

What I want to do when a mail is recognised by one of these rules could be to send it to a special address, to save it with smtp-sink or return a special message.

Is this possible to do this check and apply an action within postfix or a couple of scripts called by postfix ?

Comment: You could combine your Postfix setup with some other mail server dealing with the logic, like [Lamson](http://lamsonproject.org), a mail handling framework written/configurable in Python. See [its documentation on the FSM logic](http://lamsonproject.org/docs/introduction_to_finite_state_machines.html), and the [getting started](http://lamsonproject.org/docs/getting_started.html).

Comment: The first link points to a anti-thin-hair advertisment site (in Japanese), the other two links are dead. This is a link only answer and the links have gone stale.